# Does saving username and password to a flat file with in an android app makes it less secure?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I understand that each app runs within its own sandbox.

1. If that is the case, is it safe to save credentials in a flat file?
2. Apart from saving it in the database or over the network what are
       other options in saving credentials in an app?

Comment: rooted phone can have access to all files, so yes its less secure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store application credentials in `SharedPreferences` in android app instead of store in flat file.

Comment: But if it the phone is switched off or force stopped or removed from recent apps list, Will it still retain those credentials?

Comment: Yes, It will stay until you clean the application data from setting.

Comment: it will store your data in xml file format, if you want see it you can see through ADB.

Comment: you can find more details @ https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: oh cleaning application data, You mean clearing the cache by "Settings" --> Running apps --> Clear data ???

Comment: Then this may not be a suitable option, if user does that. Thanks for the link. Any other suggestions?

Comment: If your application is connected with any server side code(any web services), then you can store on server side with your user_id or make some logical pattern to identifier unique user.

Comment: If I use a sqllite database within the app and store info there, Does "clear cache data" also removes the database?

Comment: Yes, It will clear all the application data, which means it will consider as fresh installed application

Comment: This does not answer the question asked, and to the extent that it does, it is wrong.  SharedPreferences has no security properties that are different than a flat file.

Comment: Your statement that clearing _cached_ data will delete databases is also wrong; only clearing all application data does that.

Answer (score 2):

SharedPreferences is also a flat file and isn't really save. Everyone with root access can read SharedPreferences. Location:

```
/data/data/package_name/shared_prefs
```

You should never store user credentials.
You should store some kind of server access tokens.

Comment: What you meant by "Server access tokens"? You mean store them in server side code?

Comment: If you care about security you shouldn't store credentials on server side. They can be stored as MD5 hash value. No one should know real value.

You can read about OpenID and OAuth to implement this on server side.

Comment: I prefer to store them within the phone(or app), but not easily accessible.